# intellij implement compiler plugin

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, integration, plantuml

I've taken an existing project [plantuml4idea](https://github.com/esteinberg/plantuml4idea) and now I'm trying to implement auto-build functionality.

What I mean is that the user can click a button when using [PlantUML](http://plantuml.com/) and an image representation the current UML diagram is generated (wherever you 
want).

I want to automatically generate the image files (based on user configuration) every time a build is triggered and the image file is older than the source file).

I've been struggling to get a clear idea of what needs to be implemented.

Do I run an external build and effectively ship a PlantUML SDK?
Do I listen for build event hooks to fire, then override some behavior?
Do I integrate with the [CompilerManager](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/compiler/openapi/src/com/intellij/openapi/compiler/CompilerManager.java)
Is there another approach?

There seems a paucity of straightforward information on the net, hence I'm asking here in the hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: hey @bryan, did you find the answer to your question?

Comment: Side note related to image generation: you can run PlantUML from the [Command line](http://plantuml.com/command_line.html).

Comment: Thanks @Ricardo - yep aware of that. Trying to improve the Intellij integration though.